# Highcharts tooltipRefresh check for hovered item

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In Highcharts, I am currently using `tooltipRefresh` to run a function that renders dynamic content within the current tooltip.

For example, I am using:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        tooltipRefresh: function (e) {
            createTableChartGauge();
        }
    }
}
```

I only want `createTableChartGauge()` to be run if the hovered data is a specific colour. I tried logging `e` that is passed through the `tooltipRefresh` function, although that just contains all chart data and nothing specific to the hovered data set.

How can I detect what element is currently be hovered so that I can render specific content per type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to `this.hoverPoint`, which contains actual point. So run your method only when colors match:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            tooltipRefresh: function (e) {
                if(this.hoverPoint.color === "#eefffe") {
                    createTableChartGauge();
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of null`. The object of `this.hoverPoints` is null.

Comment: Seems as if `this.hoverPoint` (wthout the trailing "s") is null a majority of the time, yet it *sometimes* returns an object.

Comment: Of course, my mistake - there should be `hoverPoint`, without extra `s`. If above doesn't work, could you create demo? Also, why don't you use `point.mouseover` event, but Highcharts event which is not part of official API? Or even `tooltip.formatter` would be better choice..